# Learning resources about web typography

Tags: typography

How do I go about learning web typography? I see many sites using nice font stacks in a way that they seems written on paper by Latex.

I've tried digging into their code, but I'm somewhat lost. Which book do you think I have to buy and study? Is there any on line resource or screencasts series do you think I need to see? I'm a true beginner in both typography and web typography.

I already own Robert Bringhust bible but I understood that although the principles are valid applying them on a web need more effort and so I interrupted reading it with the hope that a specific book on the web typography exists: any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot's of great online resources on the web, although perhaps not one main one to best them all.

I'd advise taking a look at the work of Tim Brown at http://nicewebtype.com, there is some useful information there.

Also check out the Type Study blog series on Typekit: http://blog.typekit.com/category/type-study/ for a ranging set of topics.

From those you should be able to find your way to other resources.

If you have the Robert Bringhurst bible you might be interested in this: http://webtypography.net/ which takes elments of the book and looks at them in the context of the web.